# How to add WMS to QGIS via cpp-plugin

Tags: qgis-plugins, wms, c++

I try to add a WMS layer to QGIS Desktop from my plugin (C++)

```
QString uri = "crs=EPSG:28992&layers=natura2000:natura2000&styles=&format=image/png&url=http://geodata.nationaalgeoregister.nl/natura2000/ows?
QString myProviderName = "wms";
QgsRasterLayer* lyr = mQGisIface->addRasterLayer(uri ,"test", myProviderName);
```

But in QGIS I get the message, `the extent of the layer could not be calculated because of unknown dataprovider.`

What am I doing wrong?

In QGIS Desktop manually adding this WMS layer is possible without problems.
I also tested several other WMS with same result.

Comment: Sorry, i have an error in building the uri. the code is correct. the plugin is working now.

Comment: I'm having similar problem, can you explain how you fixed it? Sorry to put this in "answer" and not in comment, but as a new user I'm not allowed to leave comments.